# Should "Fixed minor bugs" be included in a commit message?

Tags: commit

When writing unit tests i usually come across a couple of bugs in my code which i fix until my tests run. Also i usually think of some tests i forgot while fixing the bugs and add them aswell. The process goes hand in hand for me (at least if the bugs are small).

When im done writing my test code and cleaning up the (minor) bugs i want to commit. And everytime i am thinking if i should include the phrase "Fixed minor bugs" in my first line of the commit (for git log --oneline).

What do you think. Is the "Fixed minor bugs" message useful? Or is it only abundant noise in the commit messages?

**Note:** I will eventually include the bugfix information in my more detailed commit message, but i am not sure about the essential first line.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's up to you how you organise your git. I do include bugfix messages in my commits. You could also create new items under tab **issues** on github and close them when they have been fixed ( thats definitely usefull but only effective when talking about long term issues )

Comment: These smaller bugfixes i make are mostly things like nullpointer errors and other things i forgot to implement correctly on first try. Bigger issues i would track like you mentioned (some bugtracker) and work on them on separate commits, or even branches.

Comment: I rephrased the question title to better reflect my emphasis on small bugs that can be fixed in a matter of seconds.